# Room and floor numbering conventions for large to midsized dungeons: most popular, advantages and disadvantages?

Tags: gm-techniques, gm-preparation, map-making, organization

### Introduction

I have been creating some multi-floor dungeons.  It took awhile, but with time I found software, a notation format, and fidelity level that suited my needs.  The one thing I'm still not satisfied with is my method for numbering dungeon rooms.  I have tried to use third party material as a guide, but all of the published adventure modules that I own use relatively small dungeons, and therefor a room numbering system that is too simple for my needs.

### Context

My dungeons typically have the following properties:

1. 5 or more stories tall.
2. Floors below ground level, i.e. basements, cellars, lower levels.
3. Multiple points of entry.

Currently, the rooms on the ground floor are "A1","A2", etc., and then the second floor "B1", "B2", etc.  Basement rooms are "LL1", "LL2", etc.

What trips me up:

1. How to number lower basement floors
2. The order that floors should be listed in GM notes.  Do I start with the ground floor, from the lowest floor up, or from the most probable point of entry?
3. How to deal with double-high rooms that intersect with two different floors.

These dungeons are mostly for my own use, with my own group.  That said, I usually have to prep far, far in advance for our games, so it is very important to organize my notes in the most intuitive way possible, as if a complete stranger will be using them.  In the past, I have left out critical information because of bad note organization and formatting.  Making things look professional is helpful and important to me.  I do have some interest in sharing this material with a broader audience one day.

### Question

Of course I am **not** looking for *the best room numbering system* — that wouldn't be SE appropriate.  Instead, I am soliciting examples of different RPG room numbering systems that have become the **most popular** over the years.  A top 3 list of the most commonly used systems, for example.  In addition, please provide an explanation of how these different systems meet or do not meet the aforementioned criteria?

Comment: *What's the best room-numbering system?* will, for some, garner their close vote as it *sounds* like an opinion question. I'd argue that anyone with a degree of similar experience can offer evidence and practical reasons *why* a particular numbering system is superior to others, therefore backing up that opinion (the bar an answer must clear). However, I fear that asking for answers to list the Top 3 Room Numbering Systems is a (*ew!*) shopping question, and those are a no-go. Have you considered posing this question on a [discussion forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/8610)?

Comment: Agree with Hey_I_Can_Chan and maybe you could make the question be specifically about just one particular room numbering system -- your current one.  And ask about what practical game-management issues might arise from using that system on a large and complicated multi-level above-and-below ground dungeon (very specific test case). Still might seem opinion-based a little, but certainly doesn't seem like shopping.

Comment: @HeyICanChan  My question, as stated in the title and body, is what is the most *popular* room numbering system. I very explicitly state that I am not asking for best.  "Most popular" is not a subjective question: it's just asking what systems are most often used.

Comment: @ValleyLad I am actually asking a much simpler, narrower question: what room numbering systems are most often used for large dungeons?  Please let me know how I can be more clear about what I am asking, because it seems people are assuming I am asking something entirely different.

Comment: My apologies. What about the following: "How can I number the rooms of my megadungeon so as to meet these criteria?" Then specify that answers need to explain how the numbering system meets those criteria rather than just offering random systems. (Both *What room numbering systems are most often used for large dungeons?* and *What room numbering systems are popular for large dungeons?* will see folks focus on *most often* and *popular* and the the question likely held with the justification that either survey is impossible therefore the question opinion-based.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan  Thank you, edited.  If I specified a game system, for example Dungeons and Dragons, would that make such a survey more viable?  Presumably, official products must have some level of format consistency, even if it changes with different versions?

Comment: I think you overestimate the editorial division of even major RPG publishers. Map consistency between products, I suspect, is an extremely low priority. `:-)` You *could* specify a system, but I'm not sure it would help. The kind of assistance you need is just as valuable if it comes from a *Shadowrun* product detailing a skyscraper or a *Traveller* product detailing a generation ship. You can try to limit it further by system, but you need big maps with big keys, and I think a system tag'll shrink your sample size to useless. <- Totally opinion, by the way.

Comment: (That said, a handful of megadungeons were published for *Dungeons & Dragons* generally. Asking for a summary of the room numbering systems of *Undermountain*, *World's Largest Dungeon*, or *Rappan Athuk* might be a thing.)

Comment: How are you measuring "most common" and "most popular" here? Appearing in the most adventures? Used by the most systems? Used by the most systems factoring the popularity of said system? I'm not sure that anybody can realistically have the data to answer any of these.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Wow. Déjà vu. `:-)` (See my comment starting, "My apologies….")

Comment: @HeyICanChan yeah I see it :) however OP has not fixed the issue and I think it deserves to be pulled out and emphasized. As written, I just don't think the question can possibly be answered.

Comment: Just to state it clearly: surveys are categorically off topic for RPG.se.

Comment: What is your problem to solve here?  before there was an internet, DMs the world over made room keys/numbering systems that made sense to them so that they knew what was in various rooms.  What is it about this process that is *a problem* for you?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast  I tried to capture this under "What trips me up".  I don't think there's any way to save the question though.  When I tried to ask something narrow and objective, it's flagged as too broad.  If I started with the specific issue I'm having and asked for a system that would best address it, the question would be flagged as "opinion-based".

Comment: @PinkSweetener Since you have to organize your notes in a way that is *most intuitive* {to you}, I am at a loss to understand how we strangers on the internet, however well-intentioned, can get inside of your head and do that.  If the point of your question regards publication or dissemination to the public, I at least am beginning to see the problem that you are hoping to solve.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast  That's why I was just hoping to get a breakdown on some of the most common ways of formatting room numbers - so I could have a list of options to choose from.  How many could there really be?  It didn't seem like a big ask.  There are lots of questions on GM convention and best practices.  People provide breakdowns of most popular methods of roleplaying, most popular methods of running perception checks, most popular methods of making combat go faster.  I'm just looking for most popular method of assigning a number and letter to a room?

Comment: gm techniques as a category?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast tagged!

Comment: @PinkSweetener "*How many could there really be?*" about one per GM. Give or take. Formatting room numbers is nothing really like perception checks, for example. Because room numbers *don't matter*. They are only relevant to the GM and only at the time. One might number them in sequence, one in a grid pattern , third in a spiral going to the middle, another in a spiral *from* the middle. Furthermore, one might have a different definition for "sequence" - 1a, 1b, 1c, etc are the first rooms available, then followed by 2a, 2b, etc. Still another GM might just name as colours.

Comment: @PinkSweetener whatever the GM picks, it doesn't matter to the adventure. A perception check *does*. Sure, you have your choice there but it's a lot more constrained and the consequences of each choice are a lot more clear cut. Using colours for the names of rooms might or might not make sense. And different people might put colours in various orders. Or none at all.

Comment: For this kind of question, a [discussion forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/321) would be suitable. That way you don’t need to change it at all and people *can* just tell you about however many systems are out there. Discussion forums are a great source of ideas to harvest from.